# Mouse picking algorithms in Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools

I'm interested in implementing some sort of 3D modeling tool. And I need a good mouse picking algorithms for various primitive types: vertices, edges, faces. Blender has most comfortable way for selecting vertices that I've ecountered. Software that I have used: 3ds Max, Blender, Maya, Houdini, ProBuilder tool for Unity3D.

What I'm talking about: I don't need pick a point pixel-perfectly, just clicked somewhere in a mesh, and closest one will be selected.

**I want to know what exactly algorithms related to selection are used in modern versions of Blender 3D Software.**

Some free papers, articles will be good as references.

Comment: Blender is Open Source - why not just look into its source to find it out?